# c# WPF Gui update with Dispatcher from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to update my `WPF GUI` from another `thread`. I've found some solutions with using the Dispatcher but it's still not working.

For example I'm using it in a catch block:

```
catch (Exception err){
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
        pConsole.AppendText(err.Message);
        pConsole.ScrollToEnd();
    }));
    return;
}
```

`pConsole` is a RickTextBox.

With the dispatcher there is an output at the `pConsole`, but the output is:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: do you try to use `pConsole.Dispatcher` (see example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.checkaccess?view=netframework-4.8#examples)) ?

Comment: Try `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: Did you try this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
   pConsole.AppendText(err.Message);
        pConsole.ScrollToEnd();
});

Comment: Thx for your replys  @PrajeeshTS @vasily.sib @Clemens. I've now tried with `pConsole.Dispatcher` and  `Application.Current.Dispatcher` and `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { pConsole.AppendText(err.Message); pConsole.ScrollToEnd(); }); `.
Unfortunately it's the same result on all of them.

Comment: Can you also try Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        new ThreadStart(() => pConsole.AppendText(err.Message); pConsole.ScrollToEnd(););

Comment: Unfortunately `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => { pConsole.AppendText(err.Message); pConsole.ScrollToEnd(); }));` has the same result.

Comment: Where is the code that generates the exception? I think the problem is there, not in your catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a problem with the code you have posted, but since you write that the `RichTextBox` actually receives the text

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

it seems like your exception handling code is working as it should, but catching an exception **coming from the code in your try block**.

In other words, check that the cause of the InvalidOperationException isn't in the try block.

Answer (score 0):

For a change, try appending the stack trace and the message to your RTF box.

```
catch (Exception err){
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
        pConsole.AppendText(err.Message);
        pConsole.AppendText(err.StackTrace);
        pConsole.ScrollToEnd();
    }));
    return;
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the code you wrote, it is just displaying the error message which was generated in the try block itself.